# TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len() について

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

僕はまだPythonをはじめたばかりなのですが、[こちらのサイト](http://cedro3.com/ai/keras-lstm-text-word/)を参考にして、文章(小説)を生成したいと思っています。すでに文章生成の元となるテキストファイルは作成しています(ファイル名…kokoro2.txt)。
そこで、以下のコードを実行すると、

```
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.callbacks import LambdaCallback
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
!pip install janome
from janome.tokenizer import Tokenizer  # 追加
import numpy as np
import random
import sys
import io

path = 'kokoro2.txt'
with io.open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read().lower()
print('corpus length:', len(text))

#chars = sorted(list(set(text)))
#print('total chars:', len(chars))
#char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(chars))
#indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chars))

text =Tokenizer().tokenize(text, wakati=True)  # 分かち書きする
chars = text
count = 0
char_indices = {}  # 辞書初期化
indices_char = {}  # 逆引き辞書初期化

for word in chars:
    if not word in char_indices:  # 未登録なら
       char_indices[word] = count  # 登録する      
       count +=1
       print(count,word)  # 登録した単語を表示
# 逆引き辞書を辞書から作成する
indices_char = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in char_indices.items()])

# cut the text in semi-redundant sequences of maxlen characters
maxlen = 5
step = 1
sentences = []
next_chars = []
for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
    sentences.append(text[i: i + maxlen])
    next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])
print('nb sequences:', len(sentences))
```

以下のように、単語が出力された後、エラーが出てしまいました。

```
ストリーミング出力は最後の 5000 行に切り捨てられました。
1634 勉強
1635 仕事
1636 なさら
(中略)
6630 善悪
6631 供する
6632 保存
6633 秘密
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-af900f3e4410> in <module>()
     41 sentences = []
     42 next_chars = []
---> 43 for i in range(0, len(text) - maxlen, step):
     44     sentences.append(text[i: i + maxlen])
     45     next_chars.append(text[i + maxlen])

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

自分でも調べて、`text = list(text)`を、エラーが出た43行目の上に追加してみたところ、エラーは出なくなったのですが、(以下のように出力されました)

```
ストリーミング出力は最後の 5000 行に切り捨てられました。
1635 仕事
1636 なさら
1637 あの
(中略)
6631 供する
6632 保存
6633 秘密
nb sequences: 0
```

nb sequences: 0　と表示されてしまい、先程のコードに続くコードを実行すると、

```
def on_epoch_end(epoch, _):
    # Function invoked at end of each epoch. Prints generated text.
    print()
    print('----- Generating text after Epoch: %d' % epoch)

    start_index = random.randint(0, len(text) - maxlen - 1)
    start_index = 0  # テキストの最初からスタート
    for diversity in [0.2]:  # diversity は 0.2のみ使用 
        print('----- diversity:', diversity)

        generated = ''
        sentence = text[start_index: start_index + maxlen]
        # sentence はリストなので文字列へ変換して使用
        generated += "".join(sentence)
        print(sentence)
        
        # sentence はリストなので文字列へ変換して使用
        print('----- Generating with seed: "' + "".join(sentence)+ '"')
        sys.stdout.write(generated)


        for i in range(400):
            x_pred = np.zeros((1, maxlen, len(chars)))
            for t, char in enumerate(sentence):
                x_pred[0, t, char_indices[char]] = 1.

            preds = model.predict(x_pred, verbose=0)[0]
            next_index = sample(preds, diversity)
            next_char = indices_char[next_index]

            generated += next_char
            sentence = sentence[1:]
            # sentence はリストなので append で結合する
            sentence.append(next_char)  

            sys.stdout.write(next_char)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print()

print_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=on_epoch_end)

model.fit(x, y,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=60,
          callbacks=[print_callback])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-d09b1cbd7b9a> in <module>()
     40 print_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=on_epoch_end)
     41 
---> 42 model.fit(x, y,
     43           batch_size=128,
     44           epochs=60,

NameError: name 'model' is not defined
```

とのエラーが出てしまいます。
Google Colaboratory を使用していて、主にiPadからコーディングしています(Androidスマートフォンからも時々やります)。
どうすれば解決できるのか分かりません。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 元記事のコードには `from __future__ import print_function` がありますので、Python2 で実行しているものと思われます。そのため、`text` 変数はリスト型のインスタンスになります。一方、user15291523 さんのコードはおそらく Python3 で実行されていて、`text` 変数は(エラーメッセージの通り) generator になります。そこで、generator をリストに変換するとよろしいかと思います。`text = list(Tokenizer().tokenize(text, wakati=True))`

Comment: `Tokenizer().tokenize(text, wakati=True)` の部分を `list()` で囲んでいます。分かりづらい場合は、`text =Tokenizer().tokenize(text, wakati=True)` の次の行に `text = list(text)` を追加してみて下さい。

Comment: すみません、僕が勘違いしていました！ありがとうございます！ただ、無事に1つ目のセルはnb sequences: 105053でちゃんと出力されたのですが、それでも質問文に書いた2つ目のセルのエラーが消えませんでした… 具体的には、

`NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d09b1cbd7b9a> in <module>()
     40 print_callback = LambdaCallback(on_epoch_end=on_epoch_end)
     41 
---> 42 model.fit(x, y,
     43           batch_size=128,
     44           epochs=60,

NameError: name 'model' is not defined` と表示されます(見づらいですが、質問したエラーと全く同じです)。どのようにすれば良いのでしょうか？何度も質問して申し訳ないです…

Comment: 質問欄のコードには元記事のソースコードの `print('Vectorization...')` から `model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)` までの部分がありませんが、この部分を Colaboratory で実行しましたか？(`model` の定義部分になります)

Comment: ありがとうございます‼︎
元記事をしっかり読んでいなかったので、ご指摘の箇所を含め複数の部分が抜けていました。教えてくださり本当にありがとうございます!  「使用可能な RAM をすべて使用した後で、セッションがクラッシュしました。」 と出てしまい(何とかします)、まだ結果は見れていませんが、とりあえずエラーは出なくなりました！

Comment: テキストファイルの文字数を減らしたら無事動作しました。丁寧に教えて下さりありがとうございました！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@metropolis さんのコメントで解決しましたので、コメント部分をコピーし、回答として載せさせていただきます。
(以下引用)

元記事のコードには

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

がありますので、Python2で実行しているものと思われます。そのため、text 変数はリスト型のインスタンスになります。一方、user15291523 (現在Y.y にユーザー名変更)さんのコードはおそらく Python3 で実行されていて、text 変数は(エラーメッセージの通り) generator になります。そこで、generator をリストに変換するとよろしいかと思います。

```
text = list(Tokenizer().tokenize(text, wakati=True))
```

`Tokenizer().tokenize(text, wakati=True)` の部分を `list()` で囲んでいます。分かりづらい場合は、`text =Tokenizer().tokenize(text, wakati=True)` の次の行に `text = list(text)` を追加してみて下さい。

質問欄のコードには元記事のソースコードの `print('Vectorization...')` から `model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)` までの部分がありませんが、この部分を Colaboratory で実行しましたか？(`model` の定義部分になります)